# Is there a way to pull up @RequestMapping path with a path variable from a properties file?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

There is a way to place value of the path attribute of the @RequestMapping annotation in a properties file. For example:

```
path.status=/status
```

And use it as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(path ="${path.status}")
...
```

How to do this if a path variable is present?

```
path.status-message=/status/{message_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

That path pattern added in property file. There is no issue in retrieve that value as follow.
RequestMapping(value = @Value("${ path.status-message }"))

Comment: "value" requires a string or an array of strings. Why should it work?